# How to end a process in c++?

Tags: c++, process, termination

Okay, so I want to write a c++ program that can end a specific process currently running. I have searched the internet and none of the solutions i have come across make sense to me. is there a simple way to end a process?

Comment: Do you want a portable solution? If not, what system?

Comment: Is this a process you have created yourself?

Answer (score 5):

On POSIX you call [`kill(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) to send `SIGTERM` to the process. On Windows you call [`TerminateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're on a *nix platform and that you have the process ID (i.e. you spawned the process yourself used some other method to infer its `pid`), using [`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) should work:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

void main() {
    /* ... */
    pid_t pid = ???;
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
}
```

It will only work under certain conditions, though:

> For a process to have permission to send a signal it must either be privileged (under Linux: have the CAP_KILL capability), or the real or effective user ID of the sending process must equal the real or saved set-user-ID of the target process. In the case of SIGCONT it suffices when the sending and receiving processes belong to the same session.